# Issue while using Polling in IBM Worklight Push Notification

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I was trying out WL 6.0 Push notification with Android device. Push notifications is working fine. I was also trying to use Polling. As per the docs from Info center,

for polling we need to invoke another procedure and after certain intervals when we get response from that procedure method push is done. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

So, as per this I have declared a new procedure named `getNotificationsFromBackend` and invoked that.

like this

```
WL.Server.createEventSource({
    name: 'PushEventSource',
    onDeviceSubscribe: 'deviceSubscribeFunc',
    onDeviceUnsubscribe: 'deviceUnsubscribeFunc',
    securityTest:'PushApplication-strong-mobile-securityTest',
    poll: {
        interval : 3,
        onPoll: getNotificationsFromBackend
    }   
});

function getNotificationsFromBackend() {
    WL.Logger.debug("hi");

}
```

Now, the problem I'm facing is when I hit `Subscribe` (from the sample app), console says it is unable to find the Adapter. Don't know whats going wrong, please help me on this.

I am getting this in console,

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0020E: Ajax request exception: Adapter 'PushAdapter' does not exist [project PushNotificationsProject]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: FWLSE0069E: An internal error occurred during gadget request  [project PushNotificationsProject]Adapter 'PushAdapter' does not exist, User Identity {wl_authenticityRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=(name:null, loginModule:NullLoginModule), wl_antiXSRFRealm=(name:rcs7pje8os4fk6p59en152iqrq, loginModule:WLAntiXSRFLoginModule), PushAppRealm=(name:ss, loginModule:PushAppLoginModule), wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=(name:c343dd38-7688-35e2-8dde-2c6acaae1930, loginModule:WLDeviceNoProvisioningLoginModule), myserver=(name:ss, loginModule:PushAppLoginModule), wl_anonymousUserRealm=null}. [project PushNotificationsProject] 
                                                                                                               com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
```

Comment: You wrote that "Push notifications is working fine", so are they working fine or are they not working fine? When do they work and when do they not work?

Comment: My query over here is, I am trying to understand the polling concept in case of PushNotification. Push works fine when I remove the poll thing. If poll is added the I always get above mentioned error.

Comment: Okay... just to verify, after adding the poll option, you do re-deploy the adapter, yes? Can you see the adapter in Worklight Console?

Comment: Yes I re-deploy it And it says adapter deployed successfully.

Comment: In Eclipse when deploying the adapter - do you see it being successfully deployed and then DELETED (there should be a message about this there)?

This typically means that there is something wrong in your polling implementation.

Comment: I do not know what going wrong over here. I will try more on it and then tell you. @Idan Adar I have another query Could you please tell me if i'm doing this analytics : {
  enabled: true
} will it show all the analytics in my Production Application Center Console ?

Comment: Read the training material and information center articles and try; if you then still have a question, open a new question. Don't mix questions.

Comment: Okey. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the problem is that your adapter was not successfully deployed. I tried this code and it works fine. Get notifications at the specified interval.

```
WL.Server.createEventSource({

    name: 'PushEventSource',
    onDeviceSubscribe: 'deviceSubscribeFunc',
    onDeviceUnsubscribe: 'deviceUnsubscribeFunc',
    securityTest:'PushApplication-strong-mobile-securityTest',
    poll: {
        interval : 3,
        onPoll: 'getNotificationsFromBackend'
    }   
});


function getNotificationsFromBackend() {

    WL.Logger.debug("hi");
    submitNotification("User1","This is Poll Notification");
}
```

The problem with your adapter code seems to be missing quotes for the function name for `onPoll` parameter.

Comment: it missing "()" , it must be like this :   poll: {
    interval : 3,
    onPoll: 'getNotificationsFromBackend()'
}