# How do I define a polling JMS adapter in IBM Worklight?

Tags: jms, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm trying to understand how to create a JMS adapter in IBM Worklight 6.2 that can listen for messages arriving on an MQ/JMS queue, and take some action (specifically, I want to make an outbound request to a RESTful service).

The Worklight documentation briefly mentions a "polling" adapter [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/admin/c_push_notification_possible_architectures.html), but doesn't go into specifics about how that would be defined/created. When I look at [the specific documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_connecting_jms_adapters_to_websphere_mq.html?lang=en) for defining a Worklight adapter to connect to MQ/JMS, it only mentions explicit `readMessage` and `writeMessage` procedures for use by a client application to read and write messages from a queue on demand.

How can I create a polling adapter that reacts to a message arriving?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "polling adapter"; Polling is an option of an adapter.

A quick search in Stack Overflow finds the following questions with polling implementation:

- [Issue while using Polling in IBM Worklight Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680789/issue-while-using-polling-in-ibm-worklight-push-notification/)
- [Worklight Event Source, what security test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077319/worklight-event-source-what-security-test/)
- As well as this blog post: [Configuring a polling event source to send push notifications](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/configuring_a_polling_event_source_to_send_push_notifications?lang=en)

Basically, you add the `poll` option to your `WL.Server.createEventSource` method:

```
WL.Server.createEventSource(
   {
       name: "eventSourceName",
       poll: {
           interval: 10,
           onPoll: callback
       },
   }
);
```

Comment: OK. For clarity, one thing that you don't say here, but which is relevant, is that typically the `WL.Server.createEventSource` call will need to go in the body of the adapter (not an adapter procedure) to ensure its executed when the adapter starts up.